# Changing API URL based on user choice

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, okhttp

```
fetchJson() 
        
        binding.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Selected: ${parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val country = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                
            }
        }
    } //All of this was inside onCreate()

    fun fetchJson(){
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics?country=Argentina")
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "mykey")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com")
                .build()
```

The spinner has a list of countries. The app is supposed to retrieve different stats from the API based on the country selected be the user. I'm trying to take the name of the country selected by the user and append it to the end of the get request url instead of "Argentina". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Get your selected country from spinner in "country" variable by using "OnItemSelected()" method

```
var country = "

@OnItemSelected(R.id.spinne_country)
fun OnItemSelectedProg2(position: Int) {
if (position>0) {

country= spinner_country[position]

}
}
```

append country varible in your url like this:-

```
val request = Request.Builder()
.url("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics?country=$country")
.get()
.addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "mykey")
.addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com")
.build()
```